# LINQ to XML: handling nodes that do not exist?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

This may be a simple fix (well, it probably is) but for some reason I just can't figure it out.

So, I have some xml that looks something like this:

```
XElement xml = XElement.Parse (
@"<Alphabet>
     <a name="A" />
     <b name="B" />
     <d name="D" />
     <e name="E" />
</Alphabet>");
```

So later in my code, I reference a node that may or may not exist in there like so:

```
var name = (from b in xml.Descendants("c")
            select b.Attribute("name")).FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

But when it doesn't exist, instead of returning null or "" it throws a NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What's the best way to check and see if a node actually exists in my linq query?  Or do I need to check if it exists some other way?

Comment: It looks like it was my use of FirstOrDefault() that was messing this up.  Thanks for the answers though - All very helpful!

Comment: can you please the solution for this I am in the same situation and using FirstOrDefault() what is the alternative

Comment: @trx - The problem I had when posting this problem was calling `Value` on my `FirstOrDefault()` query. Since the query was returning null, calling Value on it caused the error. So to test if the node is there, I should have written:

`var name = (from b in xml.Descendants("c") select b.Attribute("name")).FirstOrDefault();`

and checked `name` to see if it was null or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you're selecting the attribute - so just use:

```
var nameAttribute = xml.Descendants("c").Select(b => b.Attribute("name"))
                                        .FirstOrDefault();
if (nameAttribute != null)
{
    string name = nameAttribute.Value;
}
else
{
    // Whatever...
}
```

(I've changed it from a query expression to dot notation because the query was trivial - query expression syntax wasn't actually buying you anything.)

One problem with this solution: it doesn't differentiate between there being a "c" element but it not having a "name" attribute, and there not being a "c" element in the first place. Do you need to be able to tell the difference?

Comment: Thanks for the answer - No, I don't need to able to tell the difference so this will work great. 

I'm interested in you saying "query expression syntax wasn't actually buying you anything" - I always assumed that choosing one syntax over the other was based on preference - is there actually a performance reason to dot notation over query expression? Or maybe that's a whole different subject. Google here I come!

Comment: @Skeet - Ayende said something about that for Linq as well. Care to elaborate why it's beneficial?

Comment: No performance reason at all - just that the "from x in y" is just extra fluff in this case. See http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/01/07/you-don-t-have-to-use-query-expressions-to-use-linq.aspx

Comment: @Jon: In trying to solve my problem, I've found your answer, but am running into issues understanding what's going wrong.  I have a simple assignment, `string variable_name = x.Attributes("variable").FirstOrDefault().Value;`.  This doesn't work because if the `variable` element doesn't exist (it's optional in my schema), FirstOrDefault() will be null, and you can't dereference Value.  As a result, I get an exception.  I can check for null before using Value, but wanted to skip the extra step that you show in your solution.  Isn't there a way to do this?

Comment: @Dave: Instead of using the `Value` property, cast the entire expression to `string` - the `XAttribute` explicit conversion to `string` returns `null` if it's called with a `null` argument.

Answer (score 4):

I created extension methods to do that for me.

```
public static string GetAttributeValue(this XElement element, string attributeName)
{
    XAttribute attribute = element.Attribute(attributeName);
    return attribute != null ? attribute.Value : string.Empty;
}

public static string GetElementValue(this XElement element)
{
    return element != null ? element.Value : string.Empty;
}

public static string GetElementValue(this XElement element, string elementName)
{
    XElement child = element.Element(elementName);
    return child != null ? child.Value : string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Hey, nice.  I'm gonna use those.  Why didn't I think of that.

Answer (score 1):

`FirstOrDefault` returns `null` or an `XAttribute` which you can cast to a `string` to get the value:

```
var name = (string)((from b in xml.Descendants("c")
                     select b.Attribute("name")).FirstOrDefault());
```

or

```
var name = (string)xml.Descendants("c")
                      .Select(b => b.Attribute("name"))
                      .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var name = (from b in xml.Descendants("c")
            select b.Attribute("name").Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

or if you really need the element:

```
var name = (from b in xml.Descendants("c")
            select b.Attribute("name")).FirstOrDefault();

if (name != null)
{
    // your logic ...
}
```